# Two components interfering file events in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two instances of a component called `FileUploadComponent`, whose responsibility is to listen for file events (it's a simple template that  contains a form with a file upload button as shown below) and emit those to its hosting component via an `EventEmitter`.

Simple as it seems, when I add two of those components (Comp1, Comp2) into a template, the first instance of the button on the page seems to receive all events even from separate instances of this particular component.

So to visualize:

```
Comp1 ----------------------  / EventEmitter Fired 
Comp2 -- File uploaded ----- / -------
```

Here you can see that `Comp1` receives an event from subsequent instances of this `FileUploadComponent`, why is that ?

Here are the files:

**file_upload_button.component.ts** *(Component Decorator omitted for brevity)*

```
export class FileUploadButtonComponent {

  @Output() filesChanged = new EventEmitter<File[]>();
  private _files: File[];

  fileUpload(event: FileReaderEvent) {

    console.log(this); // !!! ====> this already triggers in the wrong component!

    this._files = event.target.files;
    this.filesChanged.emit(this._files);
  }
}
```

---

Template for button:

**file_upload_button.html**

```
<form>
  <input type="file" multiple name="file" (change)="fileUpload($event)" id="file"/>
</form>
```

---

Host template:

**some_host.html**

```
// first instance
<file-upload-button (filesChanged)="filesChangedFunc($event)"><file-upload-button>
// second instance
<file-upload-button (filesChanged)="anotherFilesChangedFunc($event)"><file-upload-button>
```

When I click the second button, the first instance sees itself responsible, the `console.log(...)` in the above code mentions that. Having gone over this code for several hours I have no sane explanation for what is happening here.

---

### PLUNKER:

> http://plnkr.co/edit/7jzjL8dRsCFPUMrVb0I9?p=preview

Comment: Could you reproduce it on the plunker?

Comment: @yurzui added plunker

Comment: Thank's then i see your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you have the same `id` and `for` respectively on your elements.

You have to use unique id:

**app/file_upload_button.component.ts**

```
let uniqueId = 0;

@Component({
  selector: 'file-upload-button',
  templateUrl: 'app/file_upload_button.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'app/file_upload_button.css' ]
})
export class FileUploadButtonComponent {
  id = `file-upload-${uniqueId++}`;
```

**app/file_upload_button.html**

```
<input type="file" [name]="'name' + id" [id]="id" .../>
<label [attr.for]="id" ...
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/siQ0jr2V5eCLKYs9OJWu?p=preview)**

Comment: Damn you are fast! It's funny, but that's exactly what I just found out! Hats off to you!

Answer (score 2):

Well without more info I can't help, a plunker would be nice, but I noticed that you are not binding the events correctly on your **some_host.html**.

This:

```
// first instance
<file-upload-button (fileUpload)="filesChangedFunc($event)"><file-upload-button>
// second instance
<file-upload-button (fileUpload)="anotherFilesChangedFunc($event)"><file-upload-button>
```

Should be:

```
// first instance
<file-upload-button (filesChanged)="filesChangedFunc($event)"><file-upload-button>
// second instance
<file-upload-button (filesChanged)="anotherFilesChangedFunc($event)"><file-upload-button>
```

You want to bind to **filesChanged** property

Comment: Thanks, but that was actually just a (lack of) copy/paste on my part. My code actually had the correct event listeners. I'll try to set up a plunker.

Comment: added a Plunker to my question