# Use same components multiple times in same page

Tags: angular, components

I start to develop with Angular. 
I created an API with data. This data is ordered like this

for each "Establishment", n "Trainings".
for each "Training", n "Groups".
I request my API with a service.

So in a page I would like to show in a expansion panel: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview
Training as the header and the groups list assosiated.

In the code I have "training-view.component" who show n Training and in this trainings, I put n "group-view.component".

supposing i have 3 training, my site will show 3 training with the sames groups (picture is more explicit) :
http://puu.sh/CogJM/476c792726.png

I tried this : [Angular 2 : same component usage repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855996/angular-2-same-component-usage-repeatedly)
But the "unique id" is not the solution. 
Maybe I cant use same component in same page, but when I use "ngFor" It works

All code are part of code.
Train-view.components.ts :

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-training-view',
templateUrl: './training-view.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./training-view.component.css']
})
export class TrainingViewComponent implements OnInit {

trainings: Training[];
trainingSubscription: Subscription;
[...]

ngOnInit() {

this.trainingSubscription = this.TrainingService.trainingsSubject.subscribe(
  (groups: any[]) => {
    this.trainings = groups;
  }
);
this.TrainingService.emitTrainingsSubject();

this.onFetch();
}
```

training view html

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let training of trainings">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
          {{training.name}}
        </mat-panel-title>
        <mat-panel-description>
          Liste des groupes
        </mat-panel-description>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <app-group-view
        [idTraining]="training.id"
        [id]="id" 
      ></app-group-view>

      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
```

app-group-view will get all groups and will do a "ngFor" on "groups.components"

so group-view ts

```
        import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { GroupService } from '../services/group.service';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { Group } from '../model/Group.model';


    let uniqueId = 0;
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-group-view',
      templateUrl: './group-view.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./group-view.component.css']
    })
    export class GroupViewComponent implements OnInit {
      @Input() idTraining: number;
      id = "tr-" + uniqueId++;
      groups: Group[];
      groupSubscription: Subscription;
      idFormation = null;




      constructor(
        private GroupService: GroupService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute){

      }
      onSave(){
        console.log('save');
      }

      ngOnInit() {

        // this.idFormation = this.idTraining != null ? this.idTraining : this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.idFormation =  this.idTraining ;

        this.groupSubscription = this.GroupService.groupsSubject.subscribe(
          (groups: any[]) => {
            this.groups = groups;

          }
        );
        this.GroupService.emitGroupsSubject();
        this.onFetch();
      }

      addGroup(){

        if(this.idFormation != null){
          let newGroup : Group= new Group(undefined,"nouveau groupe",this.idFormation,""); 
          this.groups.push(newGroup);
        }
      }

      onFetch() {
        //const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.GroupService.getGroupsFromServer(this.idTraining);

      }

      ngOnDestroy() {

        this.groupSubscription.unsubscribe();

      }
    }
```

html :

```
<app-groups *ngFor="let group of groups;let i = index" 
                [groupName]="group.name"
                [groupFormation]="group.training_name"
                [index]="i"
                [idGroup]="group.id"
                [id]="id" 
                >
    </app-groups>
```

App group is a simple compenent with html.

group.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class GroupService {

  groupsSubject = new Subject<any[]>();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
  groups : Group[] ;
  getGroupsFromServer(idGroups  : number = null) {
      let url = 'https://XXX.fr/';
      if(idGroups != null){
        url += '/trainings/' + idGroups +"/groups";
      }else{
        url += 'groups/';
      }
      this.httpClient
        .get<any[]>(url)
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            this.groups = response;
            this.emitGroupsSubject();
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log('Erreur ! : ' + error);
          }
        );
 }
 emitGroupsSubject(){
      if(this.groups != null)
        this.groupsSubject.next(this.groups.slice());
 }
}
```

See the image bellow I wrote what I want.
http://puu.sh/CogJM/476c792726.png

I hope you will understand my problem, thanks you for your help
Thomas

### **UPDATE**

I tryed the solution of @Gérôme Grignon

Training :

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let training of trainings">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{training.name}}
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
              Liste des groupes
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <app-group-view
          [idTraining]="training.id"
          [id]="id" 
        ></app-group-view>


    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

group-view :

```
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let group of groups">
          <h4>{{ group.training_name }} groupe {{ group.name }} </h4> 
        </li>
```

Result :

I have same groups for each trainings. If I go to network tab (mozillia console), it correspond to the last ajax request : http://puu.sh/Coj8v/12a01b2f72.png
Thnaks you @Gérôme Grignon

Comment: As you're saying it works with *ngFor, is there still a problem?

Comment: In the picture, there are 4 "training" (header of expansion panel) <- NgFor this for works, but foreach training there are "group-view" components and in it there is also a "ngFor" for each group, and it doesnt work. If I debug my var, data are correct, but not at the display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the communication with the service by deleting the subject and subscribing in the component.
Then iterate on the groups variable.

Service :

```
getGroupsByTraining(id) {
// ...
return this.httpClient.get(url); }
```

Group view component :

```
groups;
@Input() idTraining: number;

ngOnInit() {
this.service.getGroupsByTraining(idTraining).subscribe(data => this.groups = data); }
```

Comment: Do you use idTraining to make an http request based on this id in the app-group-view to get data and initialize "groups" with this data? (this.service.getTrainingById(id).subcribe(data => this.groups = data) for example)

Comment: it is in the "onFetch" method : this.GroupService.getGroupsFromServer(this.idTraining); i call a method who make an http request. Actually, I can retrieve correct data if i do a "console.log" who show me all id of groups. it as if all instances of "group-view" share it s variables.

Comment: can you post the ts file of app-group-view?

Comment: tell me if i'm right : you fetch data based on id, put this data in a subject into your service then subscribe to the subject to get the groups?

Comment: in the API: to  get Trainings : XX.fr/Trainings : return json [{id : 1, name : "premiere année"},{id : 2, name : "deuxieme annee"}] //\\//\\ to get Groups for training_id 1: XX.fr/Trainings/1/Groups : return json [{id, name, training_id},...]. theses requests are GET request I use "this.httpClient
      .get<any[]>(url)
      .subscribe((response) => {});" So in "training-view" I get trainings and for each trainings, I show a "app-group-view" the "groups-view" component will request API for the list of groups (2nd request).

Comment: i updated my answer. You shouldn't rely on subject : just subscribe inside the component.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot ! It was this concept were missing.